# Shamir secret sharing with two types of parties

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

Consider the [Shamir Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) scheme based on polynomial interpolation.

In this scheme, every part has the same right: one piece of information of same value as the other ones.

The idea is to adapt this scheme in following way:

Suppose that we want to share a secret among politicians and generals.
The secret can only be retrieved if **3 elements are united** and if in that group **at least one is a politician** and **at least one is a general**.

How can we do that? It is not clear to me what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: first consider this easier problem: suppose that you want them to retrieve the secret only If at least one politician and one general agree; how would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your secret is $S$. Split $S$ into 3 parts (say $S_1,S_2,S_3$) such that $S=S_1\oplus S_2\oplus S_3$.

Give each politician a copy of $S_1$, each general a copy of $S_2$, then split $S_3$ using 3-out-of-n Shamir Secret sharing.

Comment: Note that you could pick $S_1,S_2$ uniformly at random of the correct size and compute $S_3=S_1\oplus S_2\oplus S$ as an instantiation of the "Split $S$" operation.

Comment: What do you mean by $\oplus$? Is it $S=(S_1,S_2,S_3)$? E.g. if $S_1=123$, $S_2=456$ and $S_3=789$, then $S=123456789$?

Comment: @Leafar $\oplus$ means bit-wise XOR.

Comment: Yes, that was the doubt, however, it seems that it works as I stated, but of course each politician/general will know 1/3 of the secret. With the XOR each politician/general knows nothing about the secret, which is better

Comment: @SEJPM, that is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: @Leafar, yeah, letting a politician know a 1/3 of a secret is probably worse than letting them know a whole secret as they will fill in the gaps with whatever makes them look best ;)